# bash flags with optional read from stdin or file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, optional-parameters

I know this is probably a stupid question but it has me stumped.
I'm trying to write a shell script that accepts flags, and one optional variable. A file. If a file is passed, it reads from the file. If not, It reads from stdin. I know similar questions have been asked, but I can't find an answer to my specific question.

I've provided an example below that illustrates the issue. I've left some parts out (such as validation) for brevity's sake.

I can accept flags and read from a file. OR I can optionally accept a variable (file) and read from the file. If no file is passed, then we read from stdin. For some reason, when I try to combine the two (accept flags, read optional file defaulting to stdin) I get an error.

This works.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

while IFS=, read -r f1 
do
  echo $f1
done <"${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

I can call it like this... `./test.sh <<< "testing123"`
or this... `echo "testing123" | ./test.sh`
or this... `./test.sh foo.csv`.
All return `testing123` assuming that foo.csv contains `testing123`.

This Also Works.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

while true
do
  case $1 in
    -h|--help)
      echo "-h"
      exit
      ;;
    --)
      shift
      break
      ;;
    -?*)
      echo "unknown"
      ;;
    *)
      break
  esac

  shift
done

while IFS=, read -r f1 
do
  echo $f1
done <"${1}"
```

I can call it like this `./test.sh foo.csv` or this `./test.sh -f foo.csv`. The first case returns `testing123` and the second case returns

```
unknown
testing123
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. I don't understand what I'm missing here?

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

while true
do
  case $1 in
    -h|--help)
      echo "-h"
      exit
      ;;
    --)
      shift
      break
      ;;
    -?*)
      echo "unknown"
      ;;
    *)
      break
  esac

  shift
done

while IFS=, read -r f1 
do
  echo $f1
done <"${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

Called like this `./test foo.csv` it returns `testing123`.
Called like this `./test -f foo.csv` it returns

```
unknown
testing123
```

Called like this:

```
echo "testing123" | ./test.sh
```

or this

```
./test.sh <<< "testing123"
```

it returns

```
./test.sh: line 6: $1 unbound variable
```

Comment: You should use `getopt` to process flag arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
while true
```

to

```
while [ $# -ne 0 ]
```

When you run out of arguments, your code continues with the next iteration of the loop, and tries to test `$1`, which doesn't exist. Since you have done `set -eu`, referencing an unset variable causes an error and the script aborts.

Comment: Why does changing ```done <"$1"``` to ```done <"${1:-/dev/stdin}" make a difference though? shouldn't it return the error in both cases?

Comment: I just realized that in the case where I was using ```done <"$1"``` I was performing error checking to ensure that the file passed actually existed. Thanks for clearing that up!